# example for light-/heavy-tailed distribution with diverging mean excess

Tags: distributions, asymptotics, heavy-tailed

In a course we have been given the following proposition:

For a random variable $X\geq0$ with essup$(X)=\infty$

i) $F$ is heavy tailed if $\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}e_F(u)=\infty $

ii) $F$ is light-tailed if $\limsup_{u\rightarrow\infty}e_F(u)<\infty $

$e_F$ refers to the mean excess function. It is defined $e_F(u):=\mathbb{E}[X-u|X>u].$ An explicit formula is given by $e_F(u)=\frac{1}{1-F(u)}\int_u^\infty 1-F(x)dx$

It was claimed that for

$\liminf_{u\rightarrow\infty }e_F(u)<\infty$ and

$\limsup_{u\rightarrow\infty }e_F(u)=\infty$,

$F$ can be either light- or heavy-tailed.

Does anybody know examples for such distributions? I tried to find an example and constructed various discrete distributions and didn't even find any distribution such that $\limsup_{u\rightarrow\infty}e_F(u)=\infty $ and $\liminf_{u\rightarrow\infty}e_F(u)<\infty $. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you need the self study tag for this.

Comment: If we take (i) and (ii) as *defining* "heavy-tailed" and "light-tailed", then the two assertions following "it was claimed" imply $F$ is *neither* heavy-tailed nor light-tailed. This compels us to understand (i) and (ii) as being theorems, not definitions, and that the definitions actually differ from the characterizations in (i) and (ii). Please, then, *tell us what your definitions are!* Wikipedia states that [multiple definitions are in use for "heavy-tailed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution). It's hard to find *any* definition of "light-tailed."